# Split method for unordered array list

Tags: java, arrays, split

i am trying to create  method named split that divides a list into 2 lists according to a key. If  list_1 and list_2 are the resulting lists, list_1 should contain all the items of the original list whose keys are less than or equal to the key passed and list_2 should contain all the items of the original list whose keys are larger than the key passed. I will post my code so far and what other people have suggested

```
public class UnorderedArrayList extends ArrayListClass { 

    public UnorderedArrayList() { 
        super(); 
    }

    public UnorderedArrayList(int size) { 
        super(size); 
    }

    //Bubble Sort 
    public void bubbleSort() { 
     for (int pass = 0; pass < length - 1; pass++) { 
         for (int i = 0; i < length - 1; i++) { 
             if (list[i] > list[i + 1]) { 
                 int temp = list[i]; 
                 list[i] = list[i + 1]; 
                 list[i + 1] = temp; 
             } 
         } 
     } 
    }

    //implementation for abstract methods defined in ArrayListClass 
    //unordered list --> linear search 
    public int search(int searchItem) { 
        for(int i = 0; i < length; i++) 
            if(list[i] == searchItem) 
                return i; 
        return -1; 
    }

    public void insertAt(int location, int insertItem) { 
        if (location < 0 || location >= maxSize) 
            System.err.println("The position of the item to be inserted is out of range."); 
        else if (length >= maxSize) 
            System.err.println("Cannot insert in a full list."); 
        else { 
            for (int i = length; i > location; i--) 
                list[i] = list[i - 1];  //shift right 
            list[location] = insertItem; 
            length++; 
        } 
    }

    public void insertEnd(int insertItem) { 
        if (length >= maxSize) 
            System.err.println("Cannot insert in a full list."); 
        else { 
            list[length] = insertItem; 
            length++; 
        } 
    }

    public void replaceAt(int location, int repItem)  { 
        if (location < 0 || location >= length) 
            System.err.println("The location of the item to be replaced is out of range."); 
        else 
            list[location] = repItem; 
    }

    public void remove(int removeItem) { 
        int i; 
        if (length == 0) 
            System.err.println("Cannot delete from an empty list."); 
        else { 
            i = search(removeItem); 
            if (i != -1) 
                removeAt(i); 
            else 
                System.out.println("Cannot delete! The item to be deleted is not in the list."); 
        } 
    }



    public void merge(UnorderedArrayList list2,UnorderedArrayList list1){
      int num=0;
      for(int j=0; j<list1.length;j++){
        num= list1.retrieveAt(j);
        insertEnd(num);
       }
      for(int i=0; i<list2.length-1;i++){
        num=list2.retrieveAt(i);
        insertEnd(num);
       }

      }

    public void split(UnorderedArrayList list2, UnorderedArrayList list1, UnorderedArrayList list, int item){
    int listItem = item;
    while(!list.isEmpty()){
    list.retrieveAt(listItem);
    if(listItem>item){
      if(!list2.isFull()){
      list2.insertAt(listItem);
      }

    }
    }


    }
    //what i got so far from the internet
   /* void UnsortedType::SplitLists(ItemType item, UnsortedType& list1,    UnsortedType& list2){ 
ItemType listItem;

list.ResetList();
while ( !list.IsLastItem()) {
  list.GetNextItem(listItem);
  if(listItem  > item) {
       if (!list2.IsFull())
           list2.InsertItem(listItem);
    }
    else {
        if ( !list1.IsFull())
           list1.InsertItem(listItem);
     } }}
     */
```

Comment: What exactly is the problem?  In any case, your method has a `list1` parameter but seems to ignore it.

Comment: This implementation you are seeking is actually defined as the partitioning method of `Quicksort`. There are hundreds, if not thousands of code examples.

Answer (score 0):

You have a lot of code, most unrelated to your requirement.  Given the list and the key, I would simply:

- create the two result lists
- iterate through the original list, copying the element to one of the result lists depending on its value relative to key
- return the two result lists

That's all you need.

Answer (score 0):

Had this same problem. You will want to clear the two lists you have already done away with(list1 and list2) so that they are available to receive values. Look at the following code I put together, which worked in my program, as a guide. For the method call in your client, your parameters should be: (list_1, list_2, result, split) . Your new lists will be available to you in the client in accordance with their names there.

```
public void split(UnorderedArrayList list1, UnorderedArrayList list2, UnorderedArrayList list3, int key) {
      int num = 0;
      list1.clearList();
      list2.clearList();
      for(int x = 0; x < list3.length; x++) {
        num = list3.retrieveAt(x);
        if(num <= key) 
          list1.insertEnd(num);
        else
          list2.insertEnd(num);
      }
    }
```

Hope this helps.